Кавычки внутри диалога
Оправдано ли употребление кавычек в таком диалоге?
— Откуда ты узнал имя? Она с тобой говорила? Вы уже познакомились?
— «Пока нет» — на два последних вопроса. Я хочу для начала предстать перед ней в самом лучшем свете.

В ответной реплике нет ни цитирования, ни повтора чьих-то слов в диалоге, ни слов в необычном, условном или ироническом значении (см. у Розенталя).
Считаю, что употребление кавычек здесь не является оправданным. Это ответная фраза в диалоге — просто в ней пропущены некоторые слова, которые подразумеваются. Такие пропуски очень часто встречаются в диалогах.
Возможные полные реплики:
— Пока нет — [это мой ответ] на два последних вопроса.
— Пока нет — [так я отвечу] на два последних вопроса.
Из книги В. Самуйлова "Нет предела":

— Будешь писать, огромный привет от меня, здоровья ему, матери и невесте спасибо, пусть парня берегут.
— Невеста у него — что надо. Фотку показывал.
— А у тебя есть?
— Пока нет.
— Это как же так? — удивился Сарин, посмотрев на могучего сибиряка...

Из книги А. Лакс "Твоя по контракту":

— Я так сильно похожа на твою невесту?
Сейчас я стояла ровно на одну ступеньку выше Арсения и могла смотреть ему в глаза почти на равных. Арсений даже сейчас был выше меня.
— Почему ты спрашиваешь?
— Почему ты меня постоянно трогаешь? — парировала я.
Игра в крестики-нолики. Только мы адресовали друг другу неудобные вопросы, пытаясь выиграть.
— И да, и нет — это на первый вопрос. Ты мне нравишься — это на второй вопрос. Довольна?


Думаю, что кавычки не нужны:
— Откуда ты узнал имя? Она с тобой говорила? Вы уже познакомились?
— Пока нет — это на два последних вопроса. Я хочу для начала предстать перед ней в самом лучшем свете.
Поянение
На письме кавычки выглядят странно, в устной речи мы их тоже "не слышим". Можно использовать местоимение это для ясности.
